# Check if there is non-empty component content text before using Angular ng-content projection

Tags: angular

My goal is to be able to generate different component content depending on whether the selected HTML element has non-empty text content.

If there is text content then I want to display it inside a wrapper that will add additional formatting.

If there is no text content then I want to display the default text, without the additional wrapper.

Note that the example below is a very simplified version for the purpose of this question and the text wrapper will not necessarily be a simple  element. It could be a much more complicated structure of HTML elements, so the solutions of just adding styles to it to make it invisible rather fall out.

The point is also that there will be a lot of such components used on a single page, so I don't want to generate unnecessary DOM objects

Any idea how I could implement function in below sample?

```
@Component({
  standalone: true,
  selector: 'my-component',
  templateUrl: './my-component.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./my-component.component.css'],
  imports: [CommonModule],
})
export class MyComponentComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor() {}

  public get hasNonEmptyTextContent(): boolean {

    ?????????????????????????????????????
    ??? What to do here? How to live? ???
    ?????????????????????????????????????

    return ???
  }

  ngOnInit() {}
}
```

Template:

```
My component: 

<ng-template
  *ngIf="
    hasNonEmptyTextContent;
    then renderContentTemplate;
    else defaultTextTempalte
  "
></ng-template>

<ng-template #renderContentTemplate>
  <span class="text-wrapper">
    <ng-content></ng-content>
  </span>
</ng-template>

<ng-template #defaultTextTempalte>
  Default text without any wrapper
</ng-template>
```

I would like to use this component as:

```
<my-component>Some weird text</my-component><br/>
<my-component>   </my-component><br/>
<my-component></my-component>
<my-component>{{ some_property_from_parent_component }}</my-component>
```

Empty and white characters only text should be treated as an empty content.

This is a StackBlitz sample for the above case if you would like to play with it: [StackBlitz link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-fibuv1?file=src%2Fmy-component%2Fmy-component.component.html)